# Power Jack part number for YAESU FT 23R battery pack?

Tags: radio, charger, nimh

I am planning to design a small USB powered charger for the battery pack used with the radio YAESU FT 23R. I have been searching for the correct name / part number of the power jack connector shown in the following picture:

[image: Charger]

The corresponding power socket can be seen in the following battery pack. According to some measurements the socket's inner and outer diameter are around 2.54 mm and 3.85 mm respectively.

[image: Battery Pack]

Does anyone have any idea where to find this power jack?

Comment: Did you measure the diameter? Did you search for 2-pin 2.5/3.5 mm jacks?

Comment: That's indeed a mono phone (3.5mm) jack. Just use a 1/8 - 3.5mm audio cable to confirm.

Comment: I thought that there could be a power jack which resembled exactly the mono phone jack. Tahnks for that. I will try with a phone jack..